# Preventing onblur when selecting suggestion from Devbridge autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using the Devbridge autocomplete jQuery plugin and am rather stumped about how to prevent the blur event from firing when selecting a suggestion. I am not strong in the ways of JavaScript so I hope someone can point me to where I went wrong.

Here's the setup:

**The Cities HTML (as rendered by ASP.net MVC):**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="EntryViewModel_City">City</label> <span class="pull-right"><label class="label-danger" id="EntryViewModel_CityValidation"></label> <label for="EntryViewModel_VariousCities">Various Cities</label> <input class="checkbox-inline" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Various Cities field is required." id="EntryViewModel_VariousCities" name="EntryViewModel.VariousCities" onchange="disableField(this,EntryViewModel_City)" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="EntryViewModel.VariousCities" type="hidden" value="false" /></span>
    <textarea class="form-control uppercase-text text-box multi-line" id="EntryViewModel_City" name="EntryViewModel.City" onblur="validateLocation(this,EntryViewModel_County)" onkeyup="validateDuplicateValues(this)">PORTLAND</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The autocomplete setup (called from $(document).ready()):**

```
$('#EntryViewModel_City').devbridgeAutocomplete({
    lookup: cityList,
    lookupFilter: function (suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {
            return $('#EntryViewModel_City').val().split(',').indexOf(suggestion.value) === -1;
    },
    delimiter: ',',
    //serviceUrl: citiesUrl, //service not available from internet. Use array instead.
    minChars: 2,
    noCache: false,
    showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
    tabDisabled: false,
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
      this.value = this.value + ",";
  },
});
```

**The Problem:**

My cities field can contain multiple entries, separated by commas. The user should be able select any number of cities and only after the user leaves the cities `<textarea>` should the blur event fire to validate all the cities in the list. However, if one enters 'es' and then selects a suggestion with the mouse, an error is displayed stating that 'es' is an invalid city, indicating that the `<textarea>` is not updated before onblur fires. Using the arrow keys does not cause this issue.

So how would I prevent onblur from firing until after the user purposely leaves the cities `<textarea>`?

See plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/DnJ31mq40nlXrGPtMppu?p=preview